# how to get description of a user's tagged photos on Facebook using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photos

"/photos" gives creator,tags,comments,likes etc but not description of the photo. How to get description of a particular photo.

Regarding why I need this?
I want to identify photos which are uploaded by other applications. If there's some other way to know this please let me know. Right now I am going by indicators like there would be a link  in such description,more number of users are likely to be tagged etc!!